# base64_encode(pack("H*",$sha1Signature)) to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
$sha1Signature = sha1($toEncrypt)
```

//This will give b14dcc7842a53f1ec7a621e77c106dfbe8283779

```
$base64Sha1Signature = base64_encode(pack("H*",$sha1Signature));
```

//This will give sU3MeEKlPx7HpiHnfBBt++goN3k=

```
My code is calculating SHA1 and displaying the required : 
b14dcc7842a53f1ec7a621e77c106dfbe8283779


 but Base 64 Encode Result is different. When I send 
"b14dcc7842a53f1ec7a621e77c106dfbe8283779" to the following function it gives 
"ZmVkMzg5ZjJlNjM0ZmE2YjYyYmRmYmZhZmQwNWJlNzYxMTc2Y2VlOQ==" but I want it to be 
"sU3MeEKlPx7HpiHnfBBt++goN3k=".
```

my code :

```
 string toEncrypt = password+merchantID.Value.ToString()+acquirerID.Value.ToString()+orderID.Value.ToString()+formattedPurchaseAmt1+currency.Value.ToString();

SHA1 sha1Hash = SHA1.Create();

        //From String to byte array
        byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
        byte[] hashBytes = sha1Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);


        SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
string base64Sha1Signature1 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
```

Comment: "My code is calculating SHA1 and displaying the required" - it would really help if you'd show that code. A SHA-1 is binary data, normally represented as a `byte[]`. I suspect you're converting that `byte[]` into hex, then converting the hex representation into bytes again and performing base64 encoding on *that*. But we can't tell as you haven't shown us any of your C# code.

Comment: If you decode your desired result you'll notice that it's a binary result, the first byte of which is `0xb1`. Don't convert the byte array to a hexadecimal formatted string before encoding.

Comment: @Angie Could please edit your question and add the code there please?

Comment: @phuzi i added my code ..

Comment: @jps i added my code ..

Comment: This code is just wrong: don't do `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash))` where `hash` is itself a stringified `byte[] hashBytes`, just do `Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)`

Comment: @Charlieface : million thanks !!!